# About a geometric algorithm to compute $\sin$ based on the unit circle

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry, algorithms, numerical-methods

In an old post I have found a user which claims to have a geometric algorithm to compute trigonometric  functions for an angle between $0^\circ$ and $90^\circ$ based on the unit circle. Here's the relevant part:

> Start with two segments. Both will be radii of the unit circle.
>   Initially, one of the segments will be horizontal, starting from
>   $(0,0)$, ending at $(1,0)$. The other will be vertical, starting from
>   $(0,0)$ and ending at $(0,1)$. During the steps of the algorithm, we
>   will move the ends which lay on the unit circle. Each step will halve
>   the angle between the segments by moving one of the two segments in
>   the middle. We will be careful to choose which of the two segments we
>   move in such a way that the interesting angle A always falls between
>   the segments. Theoretically, the two segments will never coincide, of
>   course. But in practice, after relatively few steps, they will be
>   sufficiently close together for any practical purpose.
>
> Here is an example: Say we want to calculate $\sin$ and $\cos$ of the
>   angle $17.448^\circ$ to 3 decimal places. Therefore we will use 4
>   decimal places for all the steps that follow:
>
> Here is how we proceed: Initially, the endpoints of the segments will
>   be:   $x_1 = 1, y_1 = 0 $,   $x_2 = 0, y_2 = 1$,
>
> and the angles will be  $ a_1 = 0^\circ, a_2 = 90^\circ $
>
> Now find the mid-angle between the two:   the new "$a$" will be midway
>   between $a_1$ and $a_2$, which is    $ (a_1 + a_2) / 2$, which is $
> > 45$.
>
> This means, we will have to move the second segment, in order to
>   maintain the $17.44892$ between the two segments.   We already know
>   what will be the new angle $a_2$, but we need to calculate also new
>   values for the $x_2, y_2$:
>
> Find the midpoint of between the ends of the two segments by
>   averaging the old endpoints of $x_1,y_1$ and $x_2,y_2$: this gives $x
> > = 0.5 $and $ y = 0.5$. So the new segment is along the line from $(0,0)$ to $(0.5, 0.5)$, but this segment is too short: we need to
>   move the point $(0.0, 0.5)$ so that it falls on the unit circle thus
>   extending the segment to unit length, while being careful not to
>   change the slope of the segment. This is done by multiplying dividing
>   both coordinates to the length of that short segment. And we calculate
>   the length using the Pythagorean theorem:
>
> $length =\sqrt{0.5 \cdot 0.5 + 0.5 \cdot 0.5} = \sqrt{0.5} = 0.7071$
>
> Dividing both coordinates in $(0.5, 0.5)$ by $0.7071$ gives the new
>   point $(0.7071, 0.7071)$.
>
> And so we now have: $  a_1 =  0^\circ, x_1 = 1, y_1 = 0 $
>
> $ a_2 = 45^\circ, x_2 = 0.7071, y_2 = 0.7071$
>
> And this is all we need to proceed further to the next step.
>
> At all times,$ y_1 = \sin(a_1), x_1 = \cos(a_1)$,  and similarly $y_2
> > = \sin(a_2), x_2 = \cos(a_2)$.
>
> We can now see that if $ y_1$ and $y_2$ differ by less than $0.001$,
>   we have reduced the range sufficiently and we have found our answer.

Which follows is a table with more iterations but I can't reproduce it here, so I leave the link

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/geometry.college/IyQJ-UK-o68

The entire exposition can be found in Balevsky's first comment.

So, the questions are

> 1) I need a more detailed explanation of how the algorithm work, in
>   particular, how to continue the iterations in the case stated above.
>   How can be used to compute, for example, $\cos 20^\circ$ ?
>
> 2) How can be used this method to compute inverse trigonometric
>   functions as the autor claims?
>
> 3) How to see the process geometrically in terms of the unit circle?

REMARK: The autor says that this is not the CORDIC algorithm. In fact, this algorithm does not require a table of $\arctan$ as CORDIC.

Comment: Isn't it a [**CORDIC** algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC)?

Comment: This is simply interpolation via bisection.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Er, yes, my bad, I interpreted a quick numerical check the wrong way.